# How to multi-select text block in iterm2 with tmux?

Tags: tmux, iterm2

In basic iterm2, multi-select is simple, just hold command key and drag-and-drop or double click will do the trick. We will have some discrete highlight text, something like this:

[image]

i.e. I can have "At work" & "inversel" highlight at the same time.

But this does not work in tmux session with iterm2, hold command key and drag-and-drop will not select anything or highlight.

---

Thanks for any suggestions.

---

EDIT:
A million thanks to @Simba for the detailed explanation. But I can't find the "mouse report" switch, is this about the item2 version or I miss something?

[image]

---

EDIT2:
@Simba I found the box (Session -> Edit Session -> Terminal -> Enable mouse reporting), but uncheck it's not working, even after I restart itemr2 it's checked again everytime LOL

---

EDIT3:
After several times restart now it's working, I have no idea what's happening... Thanks! @Simba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"hold command key and drag-and-drop" to do multiple copy is a feature of iTerm2, the terminal. Within tmux, the copy action is handled by tmux, and tmux doesn't support this multi-copy feature.

#### Method 1

An alternative way: use **tmux integration mode** of iTerm2 by starting a tmux session with `tmux -CC`.

After this, the drag action is detected by iTerm2 directly. You can copy the content in iTerm2 by holding "Command" just as when tmux is not used.

#### Method 2

<kbd>Cmd + Drag</kbd> is bound to continuous selection in iTerm2. Since "mouse reporting" is intercepted by tmux, to use this feature (continuous selection), you need to disable "mouse reporting" temporarily.

1. Uncheck "Session -> Terminal State -> Mouse reporting".
2. Do continuous selection with <kbd>Cmd + Drag</kbd>.
3. Enable "Mouse reporting" to make tmux work properly.

**Drawback**: To use continuous selection, "Mouse reporting" must be disabled. But once "mouse reporting" is disabled, you can't **scroll** to previous or next page. That means you can do continuous selection in current page.

Quote from [iTerm2 FAQ](https://www.iterm2.com/faq.html)

> Q: What modifier keys affect marking a selection for copy and paste?
>   A: If you hold down modifier keys while making a selection, the behavior changes in various ways:
>
> - Alt/Option: Mouse reporting will be disabled. If you're using vim and you can't make a selection, try holding down the alt key and see if that fixes it.
> - Alt + Cmd: Make a rectangular selection.
> - Shift: Extend an existing selection.
> - Alt + Shift: Extend a rectangular selection.
> - Cmd: Make a discontinuous selection

Unfortunately, selection modifier key <kbd>Alt + Cmd</kbd> is bound to " rectangular selection" and it doesn't seem to be customizable. But you can **bind a shortcut to toggle "mouse reporting"**.

Comment: yeah integration mode works but send iterm2 command is a trouble, any solution without the integration mode possible?

Comment: @hedleyyan It's impossible. AFAIK, multiple selection is not supported by tmux.

Comment: I know in iterm2 tmux, hold alt(option) key could turn into iterm2 shortcut model, thus hold alt key and double click can select a word just as plain double click in iterm2. So I come up the thought that hold alt+command key in tmux equals hold command key in iterm2.   However hold alt+command key is a high level shortcut for item2 and terminal which is a rectangle select... that's why I ask this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367832/how-to-disable-iterm2-rectangular-selection     . Seem like you are fair familiar with tmux and item2, any suggestions?  XD @Simba

Comment: @hedleyyan Sorry, `Alt + Cmd` seems to be hardcoded, you'd better open an issue at https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues about how to disable this "rectangular selection" function. BTW, my answer has been updated.

Comment: "disable mouse reporting" works for me, thanks